Repo's packagae.json is not persisting / different from package.json of docker container
I have dockerized my monorepo NestJS backend into 3 microservices.

assets
orders
auth

The Dockerfile of each looks roughly like this

FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm config rm proxy
RUN npm config rm https-proxy
RUN set HTTP_PROXY=null
RUN set HTTPS_PROXY=null
RUN npm config list  

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build auth

FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/apps/auth/main"]

Notice that I am copying the package.json file from my monorepo into working directory of the container.
Now, the package.json has the following contents of our interest
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^10.3.2",
    "@nestjs/common": "^10.3.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.1.1",
    "@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/event-emitter": "^2.0.4",
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^10.0.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/node": "^20.3.1",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.38",
}


Notice that the nestjs/cli is under dependencies and not devDependencies.
nest cli is required to run the backend via the npm run start command like
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"apps/**/*.ts\" \"libs/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
}

Now, these microservice are dockerized; docker images -> stored on AWS ECR private registry -> pulled by my AWS ec2 instance where I have a docker-compose file like this
version: '3'
services:
  assets:
    image: ....
    command: npm run start:dev assets
    env_file:
      - /home/ubuntu/config/.env
    depends_on:
      - auth
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '4000:4000'

  auth:
    image: ....
    command: npm run start:dev auth
    env_file:
      - /home/ubuntu/config/.env
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'

  orders:
    image: ....
    command: npm run start:dev orders
    env_file:
      - /home/ubuntu/config/.env
    depends_on:
      - auth
      - assets
      - rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'


But whenever I start to run the containers via docker-compose up,  the error nest not found is thrown. I log into the containers via the interactive shell and observe their pkg.json and there in

nest/cli is under DevDependencies INSTEAD of being under dependencies

Because of this my backend crashes!
So, I wonder why is this happening when I am directly copying the contents of my package.json monorepo into the docker containers?
